# bash multiline string variable assignment failing

Tags: bash

in bash why does this work fine:

```
$ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "some text" \
"some more text"
$ ./test1.sh
some text some more text
```

but this fails

```
$ cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
text="some text" \
"some more text"
echo $text
$ ./test2.sh
./test2.sh: line 3: some more text: command not found
```

I was expecting both `test1.sh` and `test2.sh` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [POSIX Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01),

> A <backslash> that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a <newline>. If a <newline> follows the <backslash>, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The <backslash> and <newline> shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. Since the escaped <newline> is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.

This means that, in your first example, what the shell actually executes is

```bsh
echo "some text" "some more text"
```

which is the simple command `echo` followed by two arguments, concatenated using a space character when printed to standard output.

In your second example, what the shell actually executes is

```bsh
text="some text" "some more text"
echo $text
```

where the first line is interpreted as the simple command `some more text` (a single token, including the space characters) preceded by the variable assignment `text="some text"`; then, `echo $text` is executed.

To produce the same result as the first one, your second snippet may be changed into

```bsh
text="some text "\
"some more text"
echo "$text"
```

Note, also, the double quotes in `echo "$text"`, needed to prevent the shell from applying word splitting and filename generation to the expansion of `$text` (it makes no difference with your sample strings, but it would if they contained whitespace character sequences other than a single space and/or globbing characters).

Comment: wow! that's a great answer - i had no idea you could put `"\ ` (without the space between `"` and `\ `) to concatenate a string.

Comment: beware it doesn't work if there is an indent or space at the start of the second line though - before the quote.

Comment: @mulllhausen Yep, whitespace characters before the second quoted string would have the same effect of whitespace characters between the first quoted string and the backslash.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that quotes don't define a string, since everything is already a string in shell. Instead, quotes are simply a way to escape characters in bulk. `"foo"` and `\f\o\o` are identical.

Answer (score 2):

In test1.sh `echo` prints all arguments given to it - `"some text"` is the first argument, and `"some more text"` is the second argument.

Whereas test2.sh is attempting to concatenate strings and assign to a variable using an incorrect concatenation method.

To break a string across lines simply leave off the closing quote and continue on the next line, like so:

```
text="some text \
some more text"
```